# Python Selenium Can not find ID inside Div

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

[image]So I am trying to automate my daily thing to login to my ADP website but it seems whatever function I pick from selenium is does not find the ID that I am looking for which is "id="login-form_username".

Below is the part of the Selenim Python code.

```
user_textbox=driver.find_element_by_id('login-form_username')
user_textbox.send_keys(user)
user_textbox.click()

user_confirm=driver.find_element_by_id("verifUseridBtn")
user_pass_textbox=driver.find_element_by_id("login-form_password")

user_signin=driver.find_element_by_id("signBtn")
user_signin.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Also Attached screenshot of the site and error from my IDE.  Im not sure if its because for security reasons that the Website I am trying to access wont allow this kind of thing.

Thanks
Joel[image]

Comment: Can you add the error you are seeing?

Comment: Sorry I forgot,  I have attached the error on my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't share the page link and not the error you seeing we can only guess what is wrong with your code.
So it can be:

1. You are missing a wait / delay before accessing that element.
   In this case something like this should resolve your issue:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://your_site_url/")
user_textbox = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "login-form_username")))
user_textbox.send_keys(user)
user_textbox.click()
```

Alternatively you can simply add a delay before locating the elements, something like this:

```py
time.sleep(5)
user_textbox=driver.find_element_by_id('login-form_username')
user_textbox.send_keys(user)
user_textbox.click()

time.sleep(5)
user_confirm=driver.find_element_by_id("verifUseridBtn")
user_pass_textbox=driver.find_element_by_id("login-form_password")

time.sleep(5)
user_signin=driver.find_element_by_id("signBtn")
user_signin.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

but this is not the best approach.
2) Maybe there is an iframe there.
In this case you have to switch to that iframe.
3) Maybe you didn't set web driver to large enough size - if so please do that.
4) Possibly you have to scroll that input element into the view?

Comment: Sorry,  I have attached the error my previous post.  Not sure about iframe since I dont see that tag somewhere on the html lines.

Comment: have you tried my suggested solution with explicitly wait? Alternatively you can simply put a sleep instead. This is not too elegant, but can help.

Comment: So yeah,  Thanks for the suggestion Prophet.   It seems somehow resolved the first issue where it can not find the "ID".  But now the send_keys is not working anymore with the user_textbox object.                                                                              "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/joel/PycharmProjects/projtest/testing.py", line 62, in <module>
    user_textbox.send_keys(user)
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'send_keys'"

Comment: Seems like you didn't do what I suggested. Your `user_textbox` is somehow a boolean while it should be a selenium web element object

Comment: I did what you have suggested, but not sure why my var user_textbox becomes a boolean.  Also, thank you for your suggestion again about putting some delay.  I think it solved the issue now.  I was able to pass my argument to the input box.  Works great.  Thank you again.   So I just added a line "time.sleep(5)" before and after the driver.find_element line.

Comment: Well, I can add a sleep to my answer even this is not an elegant way. So, now your problem is resolved?

Comment: Yup.  Many thanks.